# How do you disable all magic comment formatting in neovim?

Tags: neovim, comments

I recently switched to Neovim's new LSP setup instead of the old Vim-based language plugins and now I get this incredibly annoying comment "helper" behavior when I hit enter after a `/**` in e.g. typescript where a new line, a space, a tab, an asterisk and then another space are added for me.

I hate this. How do I disable it?

Image for reference (with whitespace characters enabled):

[image]

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](https://benknoble.github.io/blog/2019/11/24/pics-text/). Take a look at [How to debug my vimrc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/10604) to see if you can find the exact, minimal way to reproduce the problem.

Comment: This looks like the indent for your specific filetype sets it up like that; which filetype are you editing? And what does `:verbose set indentexpr?` show?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Been on this site for over a decade, I'm aware of the rules. I posted an image in this case to show the whitespace characters, which otherwise wouldn't show up here. I also wrote out the description of the text directly before it, and explained why I showed an image....

Answer (score 0):

This may be an issue with your `formatoptions` option. Try executing `:set formatoptions-=ro`. See `:help fo-table` and `:help formatoptions` for more details on this option.